# Make laptop to wake up by keyboard and mouse

Tags: usb, laptop, suspend

The only way I can wake up my laptop (HP Elitebook 8460p) from suspend is by pressing the power button. Neither the built-in keyboard/mouse nor the external ones (connected via USB) wake the laptop up.

Things I already tried:

- Enabling the USB devices in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.
- Checking the bootlog to find out the /dev paths of the USB mouse/keyboard, then:

  ```
  udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/mouse2)
  ```

  I then checked for every device in the list using:

  ```
  cat /sys/devices/.../power/wakeup
  ```

  if it is possible to enable it, and if so, I do that.
- I have enabled wake on USB in the BIOS.

Here some outputs you might need:

**$ uname -a**

```
Linux oliarch 2.6.38-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue May 10 08:05:04 CEST 2011 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2540M CPU @ 2.60GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

**# lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b230 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 03f0:231d Hewlett-Packard
```

**# lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04)
23:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (rev 34)
25:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

**# cat /proc/acpi/wakeup**

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LANC      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
PCIB      S5    *disabled  
RP02      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
ECF0      S4    *disabled  
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
RP04      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
WNIC      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:24:00.0
RP08      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.7
HST1      S5    *disabled
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a little bit out of my element, but it sounds like you're laptop is going into hibernate instead of suspend.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GNOME go to power settings and disable hibernate after suspend this may be the problem
Because if this on your pc hibernates instead of suspend to save power (specially because you're using a laptop) so check it in GNOME settings
If you're using another DE check its settings also you may find something like that in mate or xfce power settings